# Setup the environment variable "KERNEL_DIR" symfony phpunit

Tags: symfony1, phpunit

I am encountering some problems when running some PHPUnit Tests in a different directory.

I've searched around; the answer is that I have to change the environment variable `KERNEL_DIR`.

Any idea how to change this variable?

Based on what kind of pattern, is the folder where `HTTPKernel.php` is located or some other files located.

Is it to specify the path within the new folder or the path for the original folder?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [the docs](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables):

```
#phpunit.xml
<php>
    <env name="KERNEL_DIR" value="foobar" />
</php>
```